# selectedRows() in Qml TreeView with ExtendedSelection is one step behind

Tags: qt, treeview, qml, selectedindex, qtquickcontrols

I have a treeview in the qml, the selection mode is ExtendedSelection. Whenever the selected index changes by the user I need to exactly know which tree rows are selected. Here is the TreeView:

```
Controls.TreeView {
             id: myTreeView
             Controls.TableViewColumn {
                  title: "Name"
                  role: "name"
             }

             headerVisible: false
             anchors.fill: parent
             selection: ItemSelectionModel {
                onCurrentIndexChanged: {
                  console.log(myTreeView.selection.selectedRows(0))
                  console.log(currentIndex)
                 }
             }

             selectionMode: Controls.SelectionMode.ExtendedSelection
             onDoubleClicked: {
              if (isExpanded(index))
                   collapse(index);
              else
                   expand(index);
              }

    }
```

In the example above I just try to print the selected rows to the console to make sure I have the right selection. `currentIndex` always holds the last selected index(as expected), but the `selection.selectedRows()` which is supposed to hold all the rows that are currently selected, is always one step behind. For example:

if user (while holding Ctrl) selects rows `1, 2, 3` one by one the `selection.selectedRows()` will be `null, "1", "1,2"` and `currentIndex` will be  `1, 2, 3` respectively. Combining these two together, one can get the list of all indexes that are in selected state.
My problem is that if the user releases the Ctrl and selects row `4`, then the `selection.selectedRows()` will be `"1,2,3"` although it should be `null`.
To summarize it is not possible to distinguish between the case that the user selects (holding Ctrl) rows `1,2,3,4` and the case in which user first selects rows (holding Ctrl) `1,2,3` and then releases Ctrl and just selects row `4`.

I have also tested with `myTreeView.selection.selectedIndexes`, but still the same behaviour. 
It looks like a bug in TreeView to me, please advice how to solve.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `onSelectionChanged` instead of `onCurrentIndexChanged`. With that signal you can get a list of selected indexes.

I don't know your whole code, but using the [File System Browser](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-examples.html) example provided by Qt you can check the difference.

In that example, replace

```
ItemSelectionModel {
  id: sel
  model: fileSystemModel
}
```

by

```
ItemSelectionModel {
    id: sel
    model: fileSystemModel
    onSelectionChanged: {
       console.log("onSelectionChanged - selectedRows: " + selectedIndexes)
    }
    onCurrentIndexChanged: {
       console.log("onCurrentIndexChanged - selectedRows: " + selectedIndexes)
    }
}
```

To see how both signals work.